# How to plot a fan (Polar) Dendrogram in R?

Tags: r, data-visualization, dendrogram

I'm referring to something like this:

[image]

suggested dataset for showing a solutions:

```
data(mtcars)
plot(hclust(dist(mtcars)))
```

Comment: What is the advantage of a polar representation (aside from saving space)? It looks to me like it is trickier to look at.

Comment: @nico It is more cool (-;

Comment: It is also useful when you don't have one stem...

Comment: @mbq: you missed a "good" pun there... you could have said "it's more *fan*" :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Four years later, I am now able to answer this question. It can be done by combining two new packages: [circlize](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/circlize/index.html) and [dendextend](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dendextend/).

The plot can be made using the `circlize_dendrogram` function (allowing for a much more refined control over the "fan" layout of the plot.phylo function).

```
# install.packages("dendextend")
# install.packages("circlize")
library(dendextend)
library(circlize)

# create a dendrogram
hc <- hclust(dist(datasets::mtcars))
dend <- as.dendrogram(hc)

# modify the dendrogram to have some colors in the branches and labels
dend <- dend %>% 
   color_branches(k=4) %>% 
   color_labels

# plot the radial plot
par(mar = rep(0,4))
# circlize_dendrogram(dend, dend_track_height = 0.8) 
circlize_dendrogram(dend, labels_track_height = NA, dend_track_height = .4)
```

And the result is:

[image]

Answer (score 10):

In phylogenetics, this is a fan phylogram, so you can convert this to `phylo` and use `ape`:

```
library(ape)
library(cluster) 
data(mtcars)
plot(as.phylo(hclust(dist(mtcars))),type="fan")
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: (+1) I looked for this one, but cannot found it in the `ape` package!

Comment: Bingo.  That's what I was looking for.  I wonder if there is something similar in ggplot2...

Comment: @Tal No official support for tree structures in ggplot2. Look at this Google group thread, http://j.mp/c85l5l (but it's definitively not circular).

Comment: Hello chl, thank you for the link.  I'll respond there with reference to this code as well...

Answer (score 5):

Did you see this post? http://groups.google.com/group/ggplot2/browse_thread/thread/8e1efd0e7793c1bb

Take the example, add coord_polar() and reverse the axes and you get pretty close:

```
library(cluster) 
data(mtcars)
x <- as.phylo(hclust(dist(mtcars)))

p <- ggplot(data=x)
p <- p + geom_segment(aes(y=x,x=y,yend=xend,xend=yend), colour="blue",alpha=1) 
p <- p + geom_text(data=label.phylo(x), aes(x=y, y=x, label=label),family=3, size=3) + xlim(0, xlim) + coord_polar()

theme <- theme_update(  axis.text.x = theme_blank(),
                        axis.ticks = theme_blank(),
                        axis.title.x = theme_blank(),
                        axis.title.y = theme_blank(),
                        legend.position = "none"
                     )
p <- p + theme_set(theme)
print(p)
```

Comment: `p <- ggplot(data=x)` I get this error: `ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class phylo`. What am I missing?